# JWT Token always return as Not Found Symfony2.8

Tags: symfony-2.8, lexikjwtauthbundle

Hi I have configured lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle:v2.4 with Symfony2.8 And Following is my config.yml.

```
  lexik_jwt_authentication:
  private_key_path:  "%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem" # 
  required for token creation
  public_key_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem"  # 
  required for token verification
  pass_phrase:      "%jwt_key_pass_phrase%" # required for token 
 creation, usage of an environment variable is recommended
  token_ttl:        3600
```

And this is security.yml

```
 firewalls:
    login:
      pattern:  ^/api/login
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true
      form_login:
          check_path:               /api/login_check
          username_parameter: username
          password_parameter: password
          success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
          failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        provider: my_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

I am trying to get JWT Token using post man.

http://localhost/j1/web/app_dev.php/api/login_check

I get the Token as.

```
 {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJpbmZvQGFtaXJmcmVlbGFuY2UuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUwODQ0NjQ0LCJleHAiOjE1NTA4NDgyNDR9.YKDrQ7_PaMOoW3m_reWhGb8PoNkc6wsB9EX86JNwGW4yAeG7ezqvgA4Je6AUD6BtZgGExs2oFsJTWoTAAjCyf4ZyCoUaZ7m_M7s4tJkStHgR64q1kwl1bNu21Lj0sbuAs9jjxRHzHzcNE-v8eoQf26iiXvcT1WTfhEiWQ97xtWbnTTqYzt38BjgVrqDIWDrV2CaaX-W0mHb1Ibif1VkHTgRziq1gWYgv7nqIvVVDynjIueP1HBGVBSvJPKAzzSZNWE5rcijtNVHRuH_UV0vafq1owMs8KQ8vu6pK2lH22ozHkb8V0MWHeXloHGGznAHyFnY4NPPHOwQ74hQfRT2_ibgoJ8VHtoGDsxY_8n56uIRykxk1YoXYPBEZHVEF9rCZSzCm693U-I1JNM2o6thj81tBBzTEce6csa4TbYuBEybx4zBb3pHNGAYqF3qEis63ZCzlgYsPrWOqReljfMA61QqcMcs15g6iEJ5aABgxK0FF2AuFx4_fkUDJHrZOmiasxE3ATiO4tEEf4DPizLjMsnmXgzvWkzVt1-SjBUxFLJWPGA8pCvGXrXA4-giQLWCThQ_zJ7hbGJl1_rVLT-KBoBgjV0OYaoeINh2rWXXypqo36Xh02I62_vReOCcw-He5rX6TsCuyyNAHBnP2CufC47fP-8L_ZSPWYjPxxdgOlK4"
```

}

And I am sending the token to validate the token.

http://localhost/j1/web/app_dev.php/api/locationData/8489

Authorization: Bearer {token}  with the request using post man. But I am getting alwas the result as JWT Not Found.

```
 "code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}
```

So I have debug the code with JWTTokenAuthenticator , I found it get Authorization header in request properly, but the following method does not return the token back.

```
  $jsonWebToken = $tokenExtractor->extract($request)
```

Here this alwasy return false. What to do can any one guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed it myself.